# Having A problem with reading my public and private key files

Tags: java, networking, encryption, inputstream, objectinputstream

I have a method in an encryption class that is responsible for reading my RSA key files and there respective components. To do this is use an `InputStream` object with an `ObjectInputStream` object. These are called `in`and `input` respectively. My issue is I think I might have the wrong Idea of how to use these. My error appears when I try and call this class from my encryption method to encrypt some binary data. I will link below the `ReadKey` and `Encrypt` Methods.

Both Methods:

```
PublicKey  ReadKey(String File) throws IOException{
        PublicKey publicKey = null;
        InputStream in = Encryption.class.getResourceAsStream(File);
        
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));
        try {
            BigInteger m = (BigInteger) input.readObject();
            BigInteger e = (BigInteger) input.readObject(); 
            RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            publicKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
            return publicKey;
        }catch (Exception e){
        
        }finally{
            // input.close();
        }
    return null;
        
}



public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException{
        PublicKey publicKey = ReadKey("/public.key");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        
        byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return cipherData;
}
```

To add to the context of my issue, I will explain how I use these.
I have Other methods that creat a public and private RSA keys. Now This program I use with the encryption is a simple messaging program which sends messages from a server to a client via a socket. I want to incorperate end-to-end encryption using RSA so thats where this all comes in.
I grab the entered text when the user clicks send (Saved as the variable `message`) and then run this line `sendMessage(Encryption.Encrypt(Converter(message)));` It first hands the string to my converter method which converts my message from a string to a byte array[]. This is then handed to my encryption methods above. The error then occurs when my encryption method calls `PublicKey publicKey = ReadKey("/public.key");` and appears to be an issue surrounding this `ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(in));` in the `ReadKey` method. I am a bit confused with this one as I am relatively new to these tools. Ill leave a link to a snippet of the error below:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:244)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2914)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2930)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3427)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:962)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:405)
    at oserver.Encryption.ReadKey(Encryption.java:114)
    at oserver.Encryption.Encrypt(Encryption.java:133)
    at oserver.Server.jButton1ActionPerformed(Server.java:172)
    at oserver.Server$1.actionPerformed(Server.java:105)
```

I know its a long one to read so sorry about that. Any help would be much appreaciated and if you need more info I have no problem with that. Many thanks :)

How I store my keys:

```
 public void KeyStorage() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException{
        
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); // creating a key factory object
        RSAPublicKeySpec publ = factory.getKeySpec(Pairs.getPublic(),RSAPublicKeySpec.class); // Creat a RSAPublicKeySpec object that allows us to translate between keys and there specification
        RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = factory.getKeySpec(Pairs.getPrivate(),RSAPrivateKeySpec.class); // Creat a RSAPublicKeySpec object that allows us to translate between keys and there specification
        try{
            FileSave("public.key", publ.getModulus(),publ.getPublicExponent()); // Saving the Exponent and Modulus to file public.key
            FileSave("private.key", priv.getModulus(),priv.getPrivateExponent()); // Saving the Exponent and Modulus to file private.key
        }catch(IOException e){
            // need to handle this error at some point
        }
    }
    
    public void FileSave(String fileName, BigInteger mod, BigInteger exp) throws IOException{
        
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
            
        try{
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));  
            out.writeObject(mod);
            out.writeObject(exp);
        }catch(IOException e){
            // need to handle this error at some point
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since it fails in the `ObjectInputStream` constructor call, it means that the error has nothing to do with the encryption code. It doesn't get that far. If you simple did nothing but `new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(Encryption.class.getResourceAsStream("/public.key")));`, where `Encryption` can be any class in your code, does it still fail? That should not be possible.

Comment: Why was the key file written using a Object stream? Are you sure the key file is a Java serialization file, and not a regular key file (DER or PEM)?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I may have misinterpreted the error that was being displayed so I will have another lookt at the error. I will link below how I creat the key files:

Comment: I changed my post so It now contains my methods for storing the keys. I should probibably mension that this is a learning curve for me as its a project for my A level so I have had to teach my self all this and use online guids and things. Thats why there may be a lot of poor design here but im working on it :)

Comment: It would be a pretty good idea to keep to Java's formatting "rules" and start the name of your variables with lowercase, things like `Pairs.getPrivate()` are very hard to read for Java developers. Maybe you can post something at [codereview.se] after you've created a well formatted solution. Of course `KeyStorage` and `FileStorage` (of what?) are not good names either, and key storing functions should take a key as parameter.

Comment: Did you look at the key files? I bet they are 0 bytes long, because you **never close the `ObjectOutputStream`**, so the buffer (see `BufferedOutputStream`) is never flushed. Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys!. @MaartenBodewes I will definately work on my variable names. As I have a deadline for this project and I have severly underestimated how hard this would be I have been rushing to get it working and due to this I have become sloppy with my variable names and error handelling ect. I do plan to carry on developing this program for fun once I have free time after my exams and I will take your feedback on board when I do. Thanks again :)

Comment: And @Andreas Thanks for that I forgot I never closed that. I will use a try with recources to do this, Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct problem is that you are writing to a file and reading from a resource. A resource is a read only file that is included with your Java source files (think e.g. icons in a GUI application).

You should definitely write public and private keys using `key.getEncoded()` instead. Then you can use the same key factory but with `X509EncodedKeySpec` to read back the public key and `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` for the private key.

Note that you are currently just writing the modulus and private exponent for the private key. In practice the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) parameters are written as well, and those can be used to speed up RSA private key operations.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look into using key.getEncoded(). Ill let you know how I get on. I will also Look into CRT as I have never heard about it before and it sounds interesting :)

Comment: I have been looking for examples of key.getEncoded() in some code so I can understand where exactly I will need to use in. Could you explain to my where I will use it and what It will mean for my code, if possible, no worries if not. :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all your help I have managed to creat a new algorithm that at the moment looks like its working. Ill link it below let me know what you think and sorry in advance for the variable names, im working on it.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package oserver;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;


/**
 *
 * @author sgmud
 */
public class Encryption {
    
    
    public static PrivateKey privateKey;
    public static PublicKey publicKey;
    
    public void KeyGeneration() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
        KeyPairGenerator Generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA"); // Creat the Generator object with RSA
        Generator.initialize(1024); // Set the generator to make the 2048 bit key
        KeyPair Pair = Generator.genKeyPair(); // Generate the key pair
        publicKey = Pair.getPublic(); // Set the Public Key
        privateKey = Pair.getPrivate(); // Set the private Key
        
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded()));
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded()));

              
    }

    

    
    
 
    public void writeToFile(String filePath, byte[] key) throws IOException{
        File fileToWriteto = new File(filePath);
        fileToWriteto.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream FoutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileToWriteto);
        FoutputStream.write(key);
        FoutputStream.flush();
        FoutputStream.close();
        
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
 

    
    
    
    public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String base64PublicKey){
        PublicKey publicKey = null;
        try{
            X509EncodedKeySpec KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64PublicKey.getBytes()));
            KeyFactory Keyfact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            publicKey = Keyfact.generatePublic(KeySpec);
            return publicKey;   
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return publicKey;
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(String data, String publicKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException{
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getPublicKey(publicKey));
        return cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
}

 
 
    
    
    
    
    
    
    public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String base64PrivateKey){
        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new  PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64PrivateKey.getBytes()));
        KeyFactory Kfact = null;
        try{
            
            Kfact = Kfact.getInstance("RSA");
            
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        try{
            privateKey = Kfact.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        }catch(InvalidKeySpecException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return privateKey;
    }
 
    public static String decrypt(byte[] data, PrivateKey privateKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException{
        
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(data));
} 
    
    
    
    
    public static String Decrypt(String data, String base64PrivateKey) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException{
        return decrypt(Base64.getDecoder().decode(data.getBytes()), getPrivateKey(base64PrivateKey));
} 
    
    
    
 
    
    
    
    
    
       
        
}
```